# Display Hash-Map Value C++

Tags: c++, vector, hashmap

Simple program to create a hash-map and output its key values.

```
std::hash_map<int, std::vector<char>> numPad;

for (auto const key_1: numPad) 
    {
      for (auto const key_2: key_1.second) 
      {        
        std::cout << key_1; // Does NOT work! (*error*)
        std::cout << key_2; // Works!
      }
    }
```

I am getting the following errors:

> (**error**) Error 1   error C2679: binary `'<<'` : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type `'const std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>'` (or there is no acceptable conversion)

How do I display the key_2 value without getting this error?

Comment: You should ask a specific question.

Comment: Edited. I thought it was understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used in a ranged-based for loop an `std::map` will iterate using `std::pair`. And because there is no match for `std::cout` for an `std::pair` you get an error, so instead of using `key_1` directly, try `key_1.first` to get key value of the map or `key_1.second` to get the mapped value of the map.

Comment: Thank you. It works. I will accept this as the correct answer as soon as I can.

Comment: @Daqs Try it out first though. You may see a pattern emerging.